# Checking if exec.Command exited

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a program that can run an executable, and get if the executable exited in 2 seconds

```golang
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("Files/")

for _, f := range files {
    cmd := exec.Command(fmt.Sprint("Files/", f.Name()))
    cmd.Start()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    if cmd.ProcessState.Exited() {
        fmt.Println("Exited")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not exited")
    }
}
```

This gives a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`
Because it isn't set yet (If I use `cmd.Run()` it works but that defeats the whole purpose). I've tried searching for other ways to do it but I can't find any other ways.
Are there any other ways to do this? And if so, how do I use it?

Comment: Not sure if this fits your use case, but you can force all a command to complete in a set timeframe using [exec.CommandContext](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#CommandContext). You can pass a timeout context that will expire in 2 seconds - and the command will either succeed within that timeframe (`err := c.Run() // err == nil`) or the error will be `context.DeadlineExceeded`. The job is killed if it does not complete in time - so again - this may not fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```golang
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("Files/")

for _, f := range files {
    cmd := exec.Command(fmt.Sprint("Files/", f.Name()))
    cmd.Start()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    check, _ := exec.Command("tasklist", "/FI", "PID eq "+fmt.Sprint(cmd.Process.Pid)).Output()
    output := string(check)
    if strings.HasPrefix(output, "INFO: No tasks are running") {
        fmt.Println("Exited")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Still running")
    }
}
```

Comment: Launching another process to detect if a previous process is running overcomplicates things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Always check errors.

From [cmd.Start docs](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Start)

> If Start returns successfully, the *c.Process* field will be set.

so ensure `cmd.Start` is not erroring:

```
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cmd.Start error: %v", err)
}
```

also from the [exec.Cmd docs](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd):

```
// ProcessState contains information about an exited process,
// available after a call to Wait or Run.
ProcessState *os.ProcessState
// contains filtered or unexported fields
```

so if the process has not completed then `ProcessState` will be nil - and thus you will get a runtime panic.

Comment: `cmd.Start()` is not erroring. ProcessState will be nil unless I use `cmd.Run()` or `cmd.Wait()` which all block and wait until the program has exited which is not what I want

Comment: You can run a go routine to run `c.Run()` and check the status ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934089/1218512)) after two seconds. There's no clean way to check the PID as there are limitations on [os.FindProcess](https://pkg.go.dev/os#FindProcess) (`On Unix systems ... (this)  always succeeds and returns a Process for the given pid, regardless of whether the process exists.`)

Comment: This isn't targeted for Unix systems so that wouldn't matter but I will try to use a go routine